# Reading Johann Wilhelm's surname and father's profession

Tags: germany, palaeography, transcriptions, kurrent

I'm trying to parse this text:

[image]

As near as I can read it, Johann Wilhelm's last name was Graun?  And his father, Johann Georg Graun[?] was a "Bürger und Schwein[dnenifter?]" - citizen and something to do with pigs, and married to Christina Maria Salzmann.

Can anyone read the surname and profession?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last name is *Braun* (compare the first letter with that of *Bürgers*), the profession is *Schmiedemeister*, i.e. (master) blacksmith.
The mother's name by the way is given as *Christine Maria*, not *Christina Maria*.

Comment: Not asked for, but the son's profession is more specific than his father's: Huf- u. Waffenschmidt, maker of animal shoes and weapons.